# Can fluid or smoke be simulated using particles instead of a fluid or smoke sim? And if so, how?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, smoke-simulation, fluid-simulation

I was watching [Disney's Practical Guide to Snow Simulation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4e9i0sCX7c) and towards the end of the video there was a section on using an MPM for more than just snow. This got me thinking, can particles be used in Blender to simulate a fluid or smoke (without using the fluid or smoke simulators)? And if so, how could someone do this?*

* I get that since there are probably thousands of variations on fluid/smoke sims, a general answer probably isn't possible. Could you give a relatively simple example for each?

Comment: Please specify what render engine you are using.

Comment: @cegaton cycles

Comment: This would be I cresdi my heavy on the render time as particles are far more intensive than shaders